# Separating Twitter's Streaming Response for Track/Follows

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I created a streaming query with 400 track keywords and 5,000 follows.

When I get a response from Twitter , how do I associate which follow/keyword triggered the response?

Answer (score 0):

One of the Twitter developers replied :

[Twitter dev froum link](https://twittercommunity.com/t/segregating-twitter-streaming-response/129534/4)

For matching follows: 
In nutshell Twitter documentation says:

```
1.Tweets created by the user.
2.Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
3.Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
4.Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
5.Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).
```

to match posting user Id :

```
1 and 2 are in the user object of the top-level tweet, like tweet['user']['id']

4 is the inner-level tweet, retweeted_status - so tweet['retweeted_status']['user']['id'] should be one of your follow ids.

3 can be checked in in_reply_to_user_id field, or mentions.

5 and 3 can be checked together from the mentions: tweet['entities']['user_mentions']

Additionally, if "truncated": true you might have to dig into extended_tweet
```

To match tracks I just build a regex and attempt to match against my keywords. I 've also toyed with in-memory Lucene parser.